# Guidance required for VBA code to copy data from multiple worksheets to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have written below code to copy certain range of cells from one worksheet to another sheet named as
"Report".

```
Sub sample()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

With Sheets("Jack")
lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastRow < 4 Then lastRow = 4

For i = 5 To lastRow
For col = 2 To 31
If .Cells(i, col) <> "" Then

a = .Cells(1, 2)
b = .Cells(i, 1)
c = .Cells(i, col)
d = .Cells(3, col)

With Sheets("Report")
.Range("A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = a
.Range("B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = b
.Range("C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = c
.Range("D" & .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = d
End With
End If
Next
Next

End With
End Sub
```

Above code works perfectly for copying data from single worksheet named as "Jack" but I am trying to get the data from other sheets as well. There are total 10 worksheets and I want to copy data from sheet2 to sheet7 and want to skip sheet1, sheet 8, 9, and 10. 
Any help for making a loop to copy data from selected sheets will be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the Data is the same then it should be as simple as Replacing your

```
With Sheets("Jack")
```

With

```
For x = 2 To 7

With Sheets(x)
```

And adding one more Next to the end.

So the complete code would look like:

```
Sub sample()


Dim lastRow As Long
Dim col As Long
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

For x = 2 To 7

With Sheets(x)

lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lastRow < 4 Then lastRow = 4

For i = 5 To lastRow
For col = 2 To 31
If .Cells(i, col) <> "" Then

a = .Cells(1, 2)
b = .Cells(i, 1)
c = .Cells(i, col)
d = .Cells(3, col)

With Sheets("Report")
.Range("A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = a
.Range("B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = b
.Range("C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = c
.Range("D" & .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = d
End With
End If
Next
Next

End With
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just applied and it is working. Really thank you very much for your efforts and input, its hard to find words to say thanks. I just have one question, would it be possible to merge the 'Value = a' according to the number of rows of "Value = B". Hope these two images will help to understand the question properly [link](http://i40.tinypic.com/n5juxv.jpg) and [link]((http://i40.tinypic.com/fxth03.jpg))

Comment: You can use the .merge method: `Range(xlcell, xlcell.offset(1, 0)).Merge`. You can build a list of each unique value in a range by looping through it and returning the address (`for each xlCell in xlRange | if xlCell.value like valFind then | flg = true |strAddresses = strAddresses + xlcell.address| elseif flg = true then exit for | end if`) You may want to guarantee that the search is done by descending rows, for which you can use row offsets and a `for i = start to finish` loop